# .NET MAUI Blazor Android build apk

Tags: android, blazor, apk, csproj, maui

I need to release .apk signed file. When I am trying to install my archived package, application is crashed right after loading BlazorMobileView on the device.

Deployment via release mode doesnt work also, but in debug mode all works fine.

Do you have idea what need to be changed (eg. included values in .csproj) in order to application works fine?
I have included two extra properties in .csproj file:

```
        <!--Include android supported architectures-->
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <!--Force apk build for android-->
        <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
```

But it looks like not enough.